# Getting null when using interface

Tags: java, android, interface

In my project I am using a interface to get value of `Arraylist`. I have written the code for that but whenever my app runs I get `NullPointerException`. Also I have initialized it

Code

```
public class MyResourceCustomAdaper extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    static JSONObject jsonObject;
    private static JSONObject NewDataSet;
    private static ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayMatchingJobs;
    GetMatchingJobs matchingJobs;
    GetMatchingJobsArray getMatchingJobsArray;

    public MyResourceCustomAdaper(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;


    }

    public static void setInterface(GetMatchingJobsArray getMatchingJobsArray) {
        getMatchingJobsArray = getMatchingJobsArray;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        things done here....


        return view;
    }



    public class GetMatchingJobs extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        String response;
        Context c;


        public GetMatchingJobs(Context c) {
            this.c = c;

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


            calling the web service

        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            arrayMatchingJobs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
pasrsing the json and setting the value of arraylist in the interface

getMatchingJobsArray.getMatchingJobs(true, arrayMatchingJobs);//getting null here



                            }


                        }

                    Intent i = new Intent(c, MyResourceMatchingJobs.class);
                    c.startActivity(i);


                }


            }
        }


    }

    public interface GetMatchingJobsArray {

        public void getMatchingJobs(boolean value, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayMatchingJobs);
    }

}
```

Class which used the interface

```
public class MyResourceMatchingJobs extends Activity implements MyResourceCustomAdaper.GetMatchingJobsArray {
    private ListView listView;
    private MyResourceMatchingJobsCustomList adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_resource_matching_jobs_list);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_my_resource_matching_jobs);
        MyResourceCustomAdaper.setInterface(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void getMatchingJobs(boolean value, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayMatchingJobs) {

        if (value) {
            adapter = new MyResourceMatchingJobsCustomList(MyResourceMatchingJobs.this, arrayMatchingJobs);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

LogCat

```
5338-5338/com.example.jobs_on_call.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.jobs_on_call_adapter.MyResourceCustomAdaper$GetMatchingJobs.onPostExecute(MyResourceCustomAdaper.java:253)
            at com.example.jobs_on_call_adapter.MyResourceCustomAdaper$GetMatchingJobs.onPostExecute(MyResourceCustomAdaper.java:139)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where exactly do you define the values of the ArrayList? I only see you declare it, never define any of the elements. That would be generating the NullPointerException. If it's where "pasrsing the json and setting the value of arraylist in the interface" is, please add the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
public static void setInterface(GetMatchingJobsArray getMatchingJobsArray) {
        getMatchingJobsArray = getMatchingJobsArray;
}
```

`setInterface` method is `static` but `getMatchingJobsArray` is not `static`.

As about static methods:

*Only static fields are accessible inside static methods*

So instead of

```
getMatchingJobsArray = getMatchingJobsArray;
```

if use

```
MyResourceCustomAdaper.this.getMatchingJobsArray = getMatchingJobsArray;
```

then code editor will show:

*Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field dfnsdks*

> Why getting NullPointerException?

Because class level object `getMatchingJobsArray` is `null`.

To fix this issue declare `getMatchingJobsArray` as `static` and access it using class name as :

```
static GetMatchingJobsArray getMatchingJobsArray;
public static void setInterface(GetMatchingJobsArray getMatchingJobsArray) {
    MyResourceCustomAdaper.getMatchingJobsArray = getMatchingJobsArray;
}
```

Or without using static method and variable  add one more parameter to `MyResourceCustomAdaper` class constructor :

```
 public MyResourceCustomAdaper(Activity mActivity,Context context,
                         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.getMatchingJobsArray=(GetMatchingJobsArray)mActivity;
    }
```

and from Activity create `MyResourceCustomAdaper` class object by passing Activity Context as first parameter:

```
MyResourceCustomAdaper adapter=new MyResourceCustomAdaper(
                                  MyResourceMatchingJobs.this,.....);
```

Comment: Sir i did it but now in my activity class where i am calling the interface i am not getting any result.I had debugged the application but my debugger is not going at that method of interface

Comment: @Anuj: where you are using `MyResourceCustomAdaper` adapter?

Comment: but sir i am not using the MyResourceCustomAdaper adapter in that particular Activity

Comment: @Anuj: try this way if work then we will try to fix next issue

Comment: Ya i did but i am not calling that adapter in that activity so no use of that constructor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71147/discussion-between-anuj-and--k).

Comment: @Anuj:  In `MyResourceMatchingJobs` class implementing `GetMatchingJobsArray` interface then why saying not calling it?

Comment: That only i am not getting it,I have implemented that interface still not getting it

Answer (score 0):

Your member variable getMatchingJobsArray might be null. If that's the case you'd get a NullPointerException when calling its getMatchingJobs Method.